# Use a custom database.properties file only in production in a resthub bootstrapped maven java project running in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, heroku, maven-profiles, resthub

I am using [resthub](http://resthub.github.io/docs/) to bootstrap my spring-backbone webapp.

https://github.com/resthub/resthub.github.io/blob/master/docs/spring/layout.md#environment-specific-properties

According to https://github.com/resthub/resthub.github.io/blob/master/docs/spring/mongo.md . They already have a default database properties file.

Things work fine so far, but I have to deploy the project on heroku, which has different dbname, port & other settings.

To override default db properties provided by resthub, a file named `database.properties` can be created in the classpath. But I want that file to be picked only for deployment on heroku.

How shall I proceed about configuring it such that it works locally on intellij with default db properties but takes up database.properties for heroku.

I have already read about Maven Profiles, but it talks about how to have different files for different environments and I'm looking for not to have a particular file for a particular environment, instead use the default one provided in one of the resthub jars.

*Update*

Just went through
[What is the order of precedence when there are multiple Spring's environment profiles as set by spring.profiles.active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617831/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-when-there-are-multiple-springs-environment-pro)

`resthub-mongodb` profile is always olded, in case of production (identified by `-Dprod=true`), a new profile called `heroku` is loaded which in turns loads `prod\database.properties`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:prod/database.properties"/>
```

But I guess the mongo related beans are already defined using properties defined in `resthub-mongodb` & hence, loading loading `heroku` profile to change the db properties doesn't work.

What is the solution in such a case ?

*Possible Solution*

For now, I ended up using one of the profile - `heroku` or `resthub-mongodb` depending on the system property.

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can let maven handling your environements with resource configuration.

Add in your pom or parent pom :

```
<env>local</env>

...

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/config/${env}</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This allows you to provide multiple configuration directories ; one for each your environment : local, heroku ...

With this conf, you will be able to provide a specific database.properties file for your heroku environment while keeping resthub defaults locally (not providing custom database.properties in config/local):

```
src/
   main/
       config/
             local/
             heroku/
                   database.properties
```

Adding `-Denv=heroku` option to any of your maven command run will add all `config/` directory content in your classpath. `local` is the default environement and used if no option is given.