# Providing way to configure spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is it possible to configure Spring security in a way that it reads configuration details from an external file and configures accordingly ?

(I am not talking about changing config at runtime, I am talking about reading from a file at the time of startup).

An example of **my existing** Spring security config :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean                                                             
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("userPass").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("adminPass").roles("ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {            
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override       
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
          throws Exception {

            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user").roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin1").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/test/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using multiple configurations (have a look at `Order()` annotation). What I want to be able to do is decide at the time of startup, the number and types of configuration. For example a first client may want to have 2 configs (e.g.`LdapConfig` and `SamlConfig`), a second one may want `LdapConfig` and `SqlConfig` and a third one may want 4-5 configs. Is it possible to do that?

**NOTE**: I am not using Spring Boot

**EDIT**

Summary of why I want in this way :

By **customer** I mean the company that will be buying my product. And by **users**  I mean the actual end users of the company that bought my product. So I shipped the product to 3 companies. First will configure it to have **ldap auth flow** and **google-oauth2 auth flow**. Users of this first company will be seeing a login page with these 2 options. Company 2 now might have a  **ldap auth flow** and **saml auth flow** and users of that company will be seeing those 2 options. And the company is selecting the available options before startup.

Comment: You can use Spring profiles:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: It`s a core feature, also works with a custom spring application.

Comment: If you've got a web application, you can load properties before creating the WebApplicationContext, e.g. in the overridden onStartup method of the ``WebApplicationInitializer``. We load some properties  located in the config directory of the Tomcat, that are required to initialize Spring.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne I looked at Spring profiles but to me it appears to be more helpful in selecting which config to run. In my case an entire new config might be added/removed.

Comment: Why do you need it in this way ? Which of the configurations would apply to the customer ? The config that the customer select at runtime (this is not start up time)?

Comment: Because I want to give each client the flexibility to configure the types of security they want.

Comment: How do you want to achieve this ? The customer manage the configuration through an admin console ? or the customer can set the configuration manually ?

Comment: Through Admin console

Comment: @reos even if not through admin console, do you have a solution to do it manually? The only catch is that customer will not have access to code.

Comment: You could have different configuration files (XMLs, jars) and read the configuration from the classpath. Your customer needs to put the configuration to use in the classpath. e.g. db-security-config.jar, inmemory-security-config.jar. if the customer wants to use the dbconfig they needs to put the db-security-config.jar file in the classpath and so on. Only one of theese files must be in the classpath.

Comment: When you say only one of the files must be in classpath, won&#39;t that limit the config available with each customer to only 1?

Comment: You could give "N" configuration files to the customer, but the customer can only use one of those files at time.

Comment: But in my use case That puts a restriction of not being able to use multiple Authentication Providers

Comment: I don't understand, I thougth that you wanted your customer can change the way they authenticate. And this configuration can be changed at start up time. Can you explain how do you want authenticate your users ? How the app know what authentication to use.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. The users will be presented with a login page which will contain all the config options that the customer has selected at startup. E.g a login page with 2 options: ldap(user may see login with username+password) and login with google if customer has selected say : ldap and google Oauth2 providers

Comment: OK, I understood. I'll answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could load properties, e.g. DB credentials, before creating your WebApplicationContext. Look at the following example:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // Tell the EnvironmentManager to load the properties. The path to the config 
    // file is set by Tomcat's home variable. If you change the container you might 
    // need to change this, too.
    EnvironmentParamManager.initialize(System.getProperty("catalina.home"));

    // now create the Spring Context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = 
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);
    rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    SpringApplicationContextProvider.configure(rootContext);
    // ... other config
}
```

The EnvironmentParamManager could look like this. I've decided to make it static so that the properties are accessible from everywhere even in non-Spring parts of the application.

```
public class EnvironmentParamManager {

  private static Properties properties = new Properties();

  public static void initialize(String pathToConfigFile) {
    BufferedInputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
           pathToConfigFile + "myconfig.props"));
        properties.load(stream);            
        stream.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new Error("Cannot read environment settings from file " + pathToConfigFile);
    }
  }

  public static String getMongoDBHostname() {
    return properties.getProperty("mongodb.username");
  }

}
```

When using JavaConfig, you can access your config properties at the Bean creation phase easily like this

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfig {

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
  ...
  ServerAddress address = new 
     ServerAddress(EnvironmentParamManager.getMongoDBHost(), 
                   EnvironmentParamManager.getMongoDBPort());
  ...
}
```

Of course, you are free to connect to any other services like LDAP etc. in just the same way as you load the local properties file before the Spring Context is bootstrapped. Hope that helps.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for your effort but but how will this solve the problem in my case? The example above is good if only configuration values are changing. In my case the entire configuration needs to be created. Like, in my example, when a 3rd config is found, a new Configuration will be added to Spring security.

Comment: You could manually register your beans at the ApplicationContext depending on the config you've loaded at startup. Well, I don't know if you can load an entire Configuration annotated class, but that's nothing different than a collection of its containing @Beans.

Answer (score 3):

Selective loading of components can be achived with Springs `@Conditional` annotation.

The configs would look like this:

```
@Configuration(value = "some.security.config")
@Conditional(value = LoadSecurityConfigCondition.class)
public class SomeSecurityConfig {
  // some code
}

@Configuration(value = "other.security.config")
@Conditional(value = LoadSecurityConfigCondition.class)
public class OtherSecurityConfig {
  // other code
}
```

Then, the `LoadSecurityConfigCondition.class` decides if the components are loaded:

```
@Component
public class LoadSecurityConfigCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(final ConditionContext context, final AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    boolean enabled = false;

    if (metadata.isAnnotated(Configuration.class.getName())) {
      final String name = (String) metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(Configuration.class.getName()).get("value");
      if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
        /* Here you may load your config file and 
         * retrieve the information on wether to load 
         * the config identified by its name.
         */
        enabled = ...;
      }
    }
    return enabled;
  }
}
```

In this example, the config entries can now be created with the `@Configuration` name, postfixed with `.enabled` to clarify its purpose:

```
some.security.config.enabled=true
other.security.config.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new MemoryUserDetailsManager();
       manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("userPass").roles("USER").build());
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("adminPass").roles("ADMIN").build());
    return manager;
}


@Configuration
@Profile({"profile1", "profile2"})
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("profile1")
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("user").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin1").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/api/test/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

So with `spring.profiles.active=profile1`, both configurations are loaded, with `spring.profiles.active=profile2`, only the first configuration is loaded. Of course, you can use more than 2 profiles, and you can also activate more than one profile at startup (also comma separated). You just need to divide your configurations and profiles in a way that fits your requirements.

Comment: but that still means the number of configurations is fixed and and that I will have to code and ship all the possible configurations.For example if I have shipped configuration with 1 for ldap authentication, 1 for saml authentication client can enable/disable only out of these 2. What if the client wants to provide an authentication with sql db for example. Since my shipped config class had only 2 , 3rd one will not be available. Also if client wants to configure 2 saml authentciation for 2 different urls?

Comment: @theLearner You could ship a further configuration as an additional JAR file. It is an external file and it is loaded at startup time.

Comment: I don't get your problem. Of course you have to implement all possible configs. If you want the client (client = customer?) to configure the security config on its own, tell him to override the config in a way he needs. Actually you don't know about your customer's needs in the future, so what do you want to implement?