# spring.profiles.active priority for application-{profile}.properties

Tags: spring

I would like to know the **priority** of the `application-{profile}.properties` files, if multiple `spring.profiles.active` are added.

For example:

- Let say, I have this `spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2`
- And in my `src/main/resources`, I have these files `application-profile1.properties` and `application-profile2.properties`
- If both of the files config the same property, but with different values, which one will be the one shown?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617831/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-when-there-are-multiple-springs-environment-pro) and but it doesn't cover this topics here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation, the last profile specified wins.
In your example : `spring.profiles.active=profile1,profile2`, the properties of `profile2` should overwrite the properties of `profile1`.

In the point [24.4 Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) of the documentation, you can read :

> **If several profiles are specified, a last-wins strategy applies**. For
>   example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are
>   added after those configured through the SpringApplication API and
>   therefore take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I missed that part of the documentation.

Comment: You are welcome. Some parts fairly related of the Spring Boot documentation  are sometimes exploded in two distinct parts to make it "digester". I also took some minutes to find it again.

Answer (score 2):

First Spring loads default profile (`application.properties`) and then it overrides it with your additional profiles in the same order you listed them.
So in your case `profile2` values will override everything you defined in `profile` and `application.properties`

The simplest way is to write very simple application and just check it:)

Comment: Thanks, `The simplest way is to write very simple application and just check it` I am not familiar with Spring so writing that simple application will probably take me some time, I am actually doing that right now but still not yet finished.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but a reference to the official document that I missed make the other answer the better answer, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your Spring application :)

Answer (score 0):

spring.profiles.active

Comma-separated list of active profiles. Can be overridden by a command line switch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).