# Spring: Order of profile names with SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-config

SpringBoot 2.7.1 with Spring Cloud Config

I have a test

```
@ActiveProfiles({"local","h2dbmem"})
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"server.ssl.enabled=false"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
public class SystemTest {
...
}
```

and I then run Maven to run the test :

```
 mvn -Dspring.profiles.include=cloudconfig clean verify
```

When the test runs, the console says :

```
The following 3 profiles are active: "cloudconfig", "local", "h2dbmem"
```

Although this is **exactly** what I wanted, that it ends up using the JDBC URL and credentials from the `h2dbmem` profile and **not** the JDBC URL and credentials from the  `cloud-config` profile, I could not find documentation on why `cloudconfig` ( supplied via command-line ) was added as the first entry in the list of active profiles after the profiles supplied via the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation.

To be honest, I was actually expecting the following order of profiles :

```
The following 3 profiles are active: "local", "h2dbmem", "cloudconfig"
```

... where the JDBC URL and credentials from `cloudconfig` are used, but I am glad it was not.

So question is:

Is there specific documentation on the sequence / order of profiles when they are supplied in multiple ways ( annotation, command-line, etc ) ?

Note I am aware of the order and sequence / preference of properties, which is not what I am asking.

Comment: why don't you create a `test` profile?

Comment: Check out this similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617831/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-when-there-are-multiple-springs-environment-pro , ideally it picks up from last profile, then second last and so on and so forth ! Also , it is mentioned as part of documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific

Comment: @Harsh that is not what OP is asking. The question is, how does Spring determine the order of profiles when some are given in `@ActiveProfiles` annotation and some in `spring.profiles.include` variable.

Comment: Precisely @1615903 ... That is my / the question.